# how can I count total metrics metrics on keyed state Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to to design Flink Application for streaming data from many (2-3 hundreds) Kafka topics to Greenplum tables. Each topic should be applied to its own table in Greenplum. For correctly applying data to Greenplum app should:

- Collect incoming messages to batches of either:

  - Up to size of messages in bytes
  - Up to time from 1st message in the batch
- Unload batch to CSV file
- Insert data from this file via Greenplum external table capabilities.

My current design is following:

- Flink Kafka source, which reads all partitions for all required topics (say, 1000 topic partitions)
- keyBy by topic name for partition all incoming message by topic
- Process function that:

  - Adds incoming message to its state (keyed state)
  - Registers a timer, which checks size of messages (in context of topic name - key) and messages timestamp and if threshold is achieved - apply state to GP and clear state

The problem is that I cannot measure each parallel instance of my process functions’ memory usage and sometimes my process function fails with OOM. Since this is a process function that processed Keyed stream, I have an access to state in context of current key (topic name in my case) and I can count the size only by each topic.

As a solution I can create as many Flink Jobs as the number of topics I need to stream, redesign Process function to Sink function, check batch size on checkpoint (instead of timer in Process function). But the number of topics is big, so the more topics I should stream, the more jobs I should manage, this becomes a big challenge.

I am looking for an advise how can I collect metrics in parallel instance of keyed streams’ process function. Is it possible in Flink?